# Sql connection security

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, winforms

I use the code bellow to connect to my database on my website:

```
 string tempstr = "Data Source=" + "72.55.---.---" + ";Initial Catalog=-------;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=" + "MYUSER" + ";Password=" + "MYPASS";

 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(tempstr);
 con.Open();
```

Is it secure enough ? or someone who is not professional hacker can capture the username and the password which is sent from his/her computer to my database !?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Secure enough for _what_? Security is not black and white. It depends on where this runs and what you are trying to secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings like the above will be stored in plain text in the executable.

If the "attacker" has access to the DLL, it is a simple thing to dump all the strings contained in it - including the connection string.

If you want to secure the connection string, a common practice is to store it in the `connectionStrings` section of the application `.config` file and [encrypt it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx).